# Error in Composer Identity Request

Tags: hyperledger-composer

When I make a request for identity in composer, always give this error:

> composer identity request -c  PeerAdmin@orgx-network-xxx -u admin -s adminpw -d alice
>
> Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]

What can cause this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the Fabric CA server container on port 7054 is not started or is not listening, or not bound to that address/port.